# Books on Mathematical Games

Tags: soft-question, big-list

I am looking for books on mathematical games that don't include probability. For example, books that cover
the game of nims and other such stuff. Could I get some recommendations on it? I would prefer a book with good exercises and that actively engage the reader by inducing loopholes in arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You might enjoy [Lessons in Play: An Introduction to Combinatorial Game Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1482243032) by Albert, Nowakowski & Wolfe.